# how to conditionally update a model based on form input

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms, devise

I have a 'settings' page where a user can update their info along with their password. There is a password and password_confirmation field on the same form as a name and email field. What is the proper way of doing this? If I just put the password fields on the same form and the user doesn't try to change it, it gives me a password can't be blank validation error. Is there a 'proper' way of doing this?

EDIT: i'm using devise by the way

EDIT: here's my User model code:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  # Include default devise modules. Others available are:
  # :token_authenticatable, :encryptable, :confirmable, :lockable, :timeoutable and :omniauthable
  devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
         :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable

  # Setup accessible (or protected) attributes for your model
  attr_accessible :name, :email, :password, :password_confirmation, :remember_me, :reset_password_token

  has_one :lineup
```

Answer (score 0):

You might try something like:

```
validates :password, :presence=>true, :on=>:create
```

so that when a user is updating their data, the password will be optional.

Comment: would this go on the User model? I tried doing this and it still says 'password can't be blank'

Comment: Yes, this would go in the User model (assuming that's where you are storing the password data).  Can you include your model code, esp. validations, here?  BTW, I've never used devise, so have no idea what sort of impact that might be having.